# How to deal with configuration variables in Python?

Tags: python, variables, configuration

I'm new to Python and I'm doing some tests with it.

What I need to know is what is the best way of dealing with configuration variables.

For example, for this code:

```
import twitter
import random
import sqlite3
import time
import bitly_api #https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python

class TwitterC:         
    def logtodatabase(self, tweet, timestamp):
        # Will log to the database
        database = sqlite3.connect('database.db') # Create a database file
        cursor   = database.cursor() # Create a cursor
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS twitter(id_tweet INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, tweet TEXT, timestamp TEXT);") # Make a table
        # Assign the values for the insert into
        msg_ins       = tweet
        timestamp_ins = timestamp
        values        = [msg_ins, timestamp_ins]
        # Insert data into the table
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO twitter(tweet, timestamp) VALUES(?, ?)", values)
        database.commit() # Save our changes
        database.close() # Close the connection to the database
```

In this code, how can I replace 'database.db' with a variable outside of the class, for a better configuration. ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) if you want to pass in configuration from the command line.

Then when creating the TwitterC class, you could pass in the configuration options you want.

```
class TwitterC:
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.database = database
    def logtodatabase(self, tweet, timestamp):
        # Will log to the database
        database = sqlite3.connect(self.database) # Create a database file
        #(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) out of the Python Standard Library.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a python script that include the configuration variables:
config.py:

```
dbname = 'database.db'
...
```

your file:

```
import config
database = sqlite3.connect(config.dbname)
```